# HG clone returns "abort: HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable" on Redmine VMWare computer

Tags: mercurial, vmware, redmine

I'm really new with SCM systems, so I'm starting to study Mercurial, but I'm facing a problem that I have no idea how to fix. I hope someone can point me the right direction :-) :

So, I have installed the BitNami Redmine Stack (http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine) on a Vmware computer with windows 2003 (64 Bits) as the OS. On the same VM I have installed [Mercurial-2.3](http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads/) (Mercurial 2.3 Inno Setup installer - x64 Windows - does not require admin rights) , and restarted. after that , created a directory (e:\helloworld) and I have initialized the directory with some basic the HG commands (HG Init, HG Add, HG Commit).

Using the host computer to confirm the correct communication with the VMWare guest computer, I have created a small project in Redmine, added a repository with Mercurial as the SCM and included the initialized directory (e:\helloworld on the server). The repository is displayed correctly in Redmine, and, working directly in the virtual computer if I do some changes and perform some commits, the changes are displayed in the Redmine repository. From my current limited knowledge, all seems to be ok when I work directly in the VM, but when I try to clone the directory using HG clone from the host computer, the server responds:

```
C:\helloworld>hg clone http://redminevm/redmine/projects/helloworld 
abort: HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable
```

I also have tried with the IP address instead of the hostname, adding the username and the password to the URL, or initializing the local folder previous to try the hg clone. all my attemps return the same result. I'm assuming something is incorrect in the server, but I have no idea what it can be.

What should review on the server (or Client), in order to allow me to clone the Mercurial repository thru http?

Thank you very much in advance!

Alex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after investigating, and with a big help from the Redmine forum, I can answer my own question. I hope my experience can help someone. My question was because of lack of knowledge about Redmine and what it can and cannot do.

so;even if we can have repositories in a RedMine project, RedMine is not a repository server. Means I can link a repository to a project, but, if I want work on it thru http (or serve multiples repositories) , aditionally I need install a server like rhodecode, or use hg serve. :-)

Saying this, I was doing this incorrectly. After running hg serve , I was able to serve multiples repositories.

Comment: For anyone still out there struggling with this. It's because Git repos are not necessarily (and not usually) mercurial repos. Mercurial repos need the `.hg` file; just like Git repos need the `.git` file.

Answer (score 2):

Same error if you want to clone a **git** repo with "hg clone". Yeah, I know, I'm an idiot, but it happens, probably this will help someone.